# Adding a list of dates to a database

Tags: php, database, date, mysqli

I have two date selects on my website where the admin can select `"start date"` and `"end date"`. All of the dates from start to end will be then uploaded to the database. For example:

```
Start Date: 2015-01-01
End Date: 2015-01-05

Upload to database:
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-01-04
2015-01-05
```

I have a code already in place to do this, although it is ONLY uploading ONE date to the database, the start date. Any ideas how I would get this working to upload all of the dates between the selected start and end dates? Here is my current code:

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "u779108225_admin";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "u779108225_main";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$date_from = $_POST['date_from']; 
$date_from = strtotime($date_from); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp

// Specify the end date. This date can be any English textual format
$date_to = $_POST['date_to'];
$date_to = strtotime($date_to); // Convert date to a UNIX timestamp

// Loop from the start date to end date and output all dates inbetween
for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400) {
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $i);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO calendar (date)
VALUES
('$date')";

}


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
// Specify the start date. This date can be any English textual format



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only execute your last query as you overwrite `$sql` in each loop iteration. Move your execute statement into your loop:

```
for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400) {
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $i);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO calendar (date) VALUES ('$date')";
     if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

or make one query and execute that:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO calendar (date) VALUES ";
$values = array();
for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400) {
    $date = date("Y-m-d", $i);
    $values[] = "('$date')";

}
$sql .= implode(',', $values);
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks for the answer! Would this also work for doing the same query but deleting the dates instead of adding them? As I would need to implement that feature too?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use DateTime objects over timestamps etc.

Your for loop was setting the query multiple times, however you were only executing the query once.

This is a fixed version using DateTime.

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "u779108225_admin";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "u779108225_main";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $date_from = $_POST['date_from']; 
    $date_from = new DateTime($date_from);

    $date_to = $_POST['date_to'];
    $date_to = new DateTime($date_to);

    $cur_date = $date_from;
    while($cur_date < $date_to) {
        $date = $cur_date->format('Y-m-d');
        $sql = "
            INSERT INTO calendar (date)
            VALUES
            ('$date');
        ";
        $cur_date->modify('+1 day');

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Date inserted: {$date}";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }

    $conn->close();

}
```